# Extend Volume failed, but partition was extended

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Our notification system alerted me this morning that one of the virtual servers in a small cluster was running out of space on one of its disks. To head off the same on the other servers and other disks, I hopped into vSphere and expanded the size of all disks on all the servers, then hopped into Server Manager to extend each volume.

For 3 of the servers, this worked like a charm, but on one server, one disk failed to extend -- the error in Server Manager was simply "Extend Failed". Logging into that server and opening Disk Management, I can see that the partition has been extended to 120 GB as it should, but the volume still has only an 80 GB capacity:
[image: Volumes]

[image: Disk 2 (E:) partition]

I'm less concerned with how this happened than I am with how to fix it now that it has. I can't extend it because "Extend Volume" thinks it's 120 GB, yet the volume itself thinks it is only 80 GB. Worst-case scenario I can delete and re-create the volume, but as it would take time to rebuild the data I'd prefer to avoid that option if at all possible.

How do I get my E: drive to realize that it really does have 120 GB available to it, not merely 80 GB?

Comment: Try running diskpart or the PowerShell cmdlets for disk management (I think it's `Resize-Partition`), and see what happens.  You should, at least, get a more useful error message.

Comment: Have you rebooted it? Have you tried running `extend filesystem` in diskpart?

Comment: @joeqwerty I did reboot to no effect, and had actually just found and tried the `extend filesystem` command -- with great success! If you want to post that as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running `extend filesystem` for the volume in question in diskpart.

Comment: This was exactly the magic that solved my problem!

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 3):

1. `diskpart`
2. `list volume`
3. `select volume x`
4. `extend filesystem`

[See this blog post for details](https://blog.mrpol.nl/2013/08/16/after-partition-extend-file-system-displays-wrong-disk-size-in-windows/).