# Windows Server 2008 SP2 missing disk space

Tags: windows, hard-drive

Two days ago, I logged into one of the domain controllers and found that the server has only 500 MB of free space of total 30 GB assigned. Did some house keeping and increased it to about 2.5 GB.

Additionally, I extended the disk space by another 20 GB. Now my problem, I can see the volume has 60 GB but for some odd reason, OS doesn't see it.

Diskpart sees 60 GB too. I've rescaned, ran  disk check and I'm not really sure what else to do. Help!!! (I'll repost the screenshot in a bit)

[image]

Comment: Did you extend the **Windows** volume in disk management?

Comment: Yeah, right. We did extend the disk in disk management.

Comment: Ok I think this has been asked and answered here because I had this problem once and I'm pretty sure I found the answer here. The issue is that if you don't free up enough space before you extend the volume then somehow windows can't update the volume because it needs free disk space to do that. Let me see if I can find that other question.

Comment: Check this and see if it applies: https://serverfault.com/questions/652192/extend-volume-failed-but-partition-was-extended

Comment: That would be really helpful. Do you know how much free space would be required? Currently have about 2GB of 30GB and that isn't helping. (Edit:) just seen your link. Will give that a try. Many thanks. Would you like to propose it as a solution/merge questions?

Comment: If that is your problem and the answer solves your problem, then your question is a duplicate and so I wouldn't answer it.

Comment: Thanks Todd. That actually helped me! I tried running a diskpart but that failed with the error _There is not enough usable free space on specified disk(s) to extend the volume._

Added an extra GB to the VMDK from ESX and ran diskpart again. Magic happened :)

Answer (score 0):

Extending the disk/partition in Disk Management should automatically extend the filesystem.  If not, the the `extend filesystem` command in the Question suggested by Todd Wilcox is a good idea to fix it.

If that does not help, I suggest running CHKDSK on the volume -- `CHKDSK C: /F` if you can afford the downtime.  Examine the reported statistics to confirm CHKDSK sees the proper size of your partition/disk.  If you did the reboot to run the check, you can find the results in Event Viewer from `Wininit`.

It is possible for an open file to be using up disk space that is not reported in the directory, although for it to be using up *that much* would be very unusual.